# How many possible $4$-digit integer $x$ are there if $y-x=3177$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Given any $4$-digit positive integer $x$ not ending in '$0$', we can reverse the digits to obtain another integer $y$. How many possible $4$-digit integer $x$ are  there if $y-x=3177$?

Denote $x=abcd$ and $y=dcba$. Clearly $a,d\neq 0$. Also we have $d>a$. I don't know how to proceed from here.

Any hint is much appreciated.

[The question is taken from SMO 2013 Junior Round $1$.]

Comment: In the last 24 hours you have asked 3 contest problems from the same contest. Although there is no policy barring you from doing that, some effort shown on your part would be desirable.

Comment: See what happen in the digits of numbers when you subtract one number of other. Try different subtractions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$y \gt x$, so $d \gt a$, so $10+a-d=7$  For each possibility think about $b,c$

Comment: Why $10+d-a=7$?

Comment: I had it backwards.  Consider the subtraction in the ones column.  You need to borrow because $d \gt a$

Answer (score 3):

$y-x = 3177$ so, $d>a$ and $d-a=4$ or $3$

since $d>a , a-d$ can't be 7. So, $a-d = -3$

There will be a carry to the previous digit. Solving on,

$d-a=3$ and $ c-b=2$

There are many possible - $a$ can take $6$ values$(1to6) $and $b$ can take $8$ values $(0 to 7)$

total $6*8 = 48$